# How to use my own java in websphere 8.5.

Tags: unix, websphere-8, ibm-was

My client refused to give access to WAS inbuilt JAVA and so I am not able to install my application. I have my own java installed at home/code/java. I set my JAVA_HOME as home/code/java but still when I am running the installation script in UNIX it is referring the same default JAVA_HOME under the Websphere.

Please suggest in which script I need to make the changes.

Comment: I don't really understand the part of the question about access to the WAS Java being refused and that meaning your application can't be installed ...

Answer (score 3):

You can only use the Java that is shipped with the WebSphere Application Server full profile.  It is not supported to use your own version of Java.

The WebSphere Application Server Liberty profile does support running with your own version of Java.  See the [Minimum supported Java levels](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_restrict.html%23rwlp_restrict__rest13) section in the Knowledge Center.